# Inertial and a gravitational component of two observers

Tags: general-relativity, observers, geodesics

Started reading the book "How Einstein found his field equations" by Janssen and Renn and I am already blocked on chapter 1. What do the authors means after the "split" below?:

> "What Einstein made relative [in GR] is not motion but gravity. Two observers, one moving on a  geodesic, the other moving on a non-geodesic, will disagree about how to split what is now often called the inertio-gravitational field, a guiding field affecting all matter the same way, into an inertial and a gravitational component."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am generally familiar with the works of Michel Janssen and the works of Jürgen Renn, and I endorse the interpretation of GR that they present in their works.

What Janssen and Renn are describing is about attribution.

In physics the current standard approach is to think of interactions as mediated by *field*.

It is for example assumed that the Coulomb force and magnetism are manifestations of the electromagnetic field.

That is, rather than assuming that the dynamic interaction of two charged particles is a direct particle-to-particle interaction it is assumed that a field is acting as *mediator* of that interaction.

Janssen and Renn are representative of a school of thought in which the following proposition is made:
Allow for the possibility that the phenomenon of Inertia is mediated by a field.

This inertia field is then assumed to have the property that it opposes *change of velocity*.

The measure for coupling to the inertia field is the familiar term for inertial mass: '$m$'.

The next step is to grant the following set of suppositions:

In the absence of a source of gravitational interaction the inertia field is uniform. Another way of stating that is: by default inertia is isotropic (the same in all directions)

A source of gravitational interaction induces a *bias* in the inertia field. The standard name for this bias is: 'Curvature of Spacetime'.

This biased state of the inertia field is then acting as mediator of gravitational interaction.

So in terms of this interpretation there is a fundamental assumption that there is no separate gravitational field.

Rather, according to this interpretation the field that gives rise to the phenomenon of inertia and the field that is acting as the mediator of gravitational interaction are *one and the same field*.

This assumption of a *single field* then accounts for the equivalence of inertial and gravitational mass.

So we take the standard thought demonstration of a space station that is spinning. Let the space station be ring-shaped. In that rotating ring: the centripetal acceleration has the effect of pulling G's

Do you attribute the G-load to inertia? Or do you attribute the G-load to the presence of gravity?

The point is: a local experiment cannot tell the difference.

About the word 'split' that Janssen and Renn are using. They are referring to an analogy with electromagnetism.

In terms of electromagnetism: take the case of a wire with a current running through it. Now consider the following two cases: a charged particle that is stationary with respect to the wire, and a charged particle that has a velocity relative to the wire.

The stationary-wrt-the-wire particle does not experience a Lorentz force, the velocity-wrt-the-wire particle does experience a Lorentz force. Generally, depending on the velocity of an observer relative to some system the composition of Coulomb force and Lorentz force comes out differently. There is a single field, the electromagnetic field, but depending on *velocity* of the observer relative to the system the decomposition comes out differently. Janssen and Renn refer to that decomposition as 'split'.

Janssen and Renn point out that there is an analogous split if one grants that GR is a theory of the inertio-gravitational field. For the inertio-gravitational field: how that split comes out depends on the state of *acceleration* of the observer relative to the system.